# Regular Expression URLS to Links

Tags: php, regex

Im using the following regex to convert urls to href links. It works great, however ive found a bug with it when using style tags which have a background image.

```
    /**
 * Convert urls in a string to a html link
 * @return string
 */
public static function ConvertUrlsToHtml($str)
{
    $str = preg_replace( '@(?<![.*">])\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|[a-z]\.)[-A-Z0-9+&#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&#/%=~_|$]@i', '<a href="\0">\0</a>', $str);
    return $str;
}
```

If i use the following...

```
<div class="inner-left" style="background-image: url(http://www.somewebsite/background.jpg);"></div>
```

It converts the background image to a href too.

Does anyone know how i can tweak the regex to ignore the style tags?

Comment: You shouldn't use regex to parse html.  Use DOM instead.

Comment: Use a DOM Parser to parse HTML, regex gets a nightmare to handle.

Comment: That doesnt help. Using DOMDocument doesnt work here, because its not neccessarily html. Its just a string which may or may not contain any html. So therefore, i need to find all instances of a URL in any given string, be it html or not. Then i need to create the html.

Comment: @SamuelDavidHudson: At least, using a HTML Parser will take the text in HTML (which should not be replaced) out of the way and let you work on the text alone.

Comment: Try adding another negative lookbehind:  `preg_replace( '@(?<!url\()(?<![.*">])...`

Answer (score 1):

You can start by removing HTML tags, because you don't want to replace URLs inside tags. It is true for `style=`, it is also true for `<img src=...` and `<a href=...>` and so on.

```
function ConvertUrlsToHtml($str)
{
  $strNoTags = strip_tags($str);

  if (preg_match_all( '@(?<![.*">])\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|[a-z]\.)[-A-Z0-9+&#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&#/%=~_|$]@i', $strNoTags, $matches)) {

    foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
      $str = str_replace($match, "<a href=\"$match\">$match</a>", $str);
    }
  }

  return $str;
}
```

What it does:

1. Remove the tags
2. Get all URL in the tag free string
3. Replace found URLs by a link in the original string

As it was commented, you could always try a HTML parser first to extract the text instead of `strip_tags`.